# Retrieve most common item name and its highest price from multiple categories by one SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Template table which contains multiple TypeIDs for each TemplateID.
I have an Items table whith ItemName, ItemPrice and TypeID. I need to get the most common ItemName and the highest price within that ItemName of every TypeID which attached to the selected Template.
My query doesn't work as obviously it returns multiple rows from the ItemsTable for each TypeID because of the inner joi but i can't find the way to write the query.
My query :

```
select t.TypeID, t.TemplateID, n.ItemName, n.MaxPrice
from Templates t 
inner join (select count(i.ItemName) as foundn, i.ItemName, max(i.ItemPrice) as MaxPrice, i.TypeID
        from Items i
        group by i.TypeID, i.ItemName) n on n.TypeID=t.TypeID
WHERE t.TemplateID=2;
```

The result I would like to see is like:

TemplateID 1:

- TypeID 1 - common itemname, their highest price
- TypeID 2 - common itemname, their highest price

...etc

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be very helpful.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Sorry, i had no idea i can import excel aswell. I will do by the correct way next time. However the question was answered and thats exactly the solution what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    select t.TypeID, t.TemplateID, n.ItemName, n.MaxPrice, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.TemplateID, t.TypeID ORDER BY foundn DESC) as rn
    from Templates t 
    inner join 
    (
        select count(i.ItemName) as foundn, i.ItemName, max(i.ItemPrice) as MaxPrice, i.TypeID
        from Items i
        group by i.TypeID, i.ItemName
    ) n 
        on n.TypeID=t.TypeID
    WHERE t.TemplateID=2
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE rn = 1
```

The idea is to use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate row ID for each template - type pair starting with the one with biggest `foundn`. Then, display only these with row ID = 1.